# Custom Filter not working in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I am trying to show the hierarchical data in a tree structure. When user search for a name then i am trying to use a custom filter "getSelectedNames". But unfortunately i am not able to filter it. Please help me with this.

```js
MyApp.filter('getSelectedNames', function () {
    return function (data, name) {
        var arr = [];
        var recFun = function (input) {
            angular.forEach(input, function (item) {
                if (item.name == name) {
                    arr.push(item);
                    return arr;
                }
                else if (item.children) {
                    rec(item.children);
                }
                return arr;
            });           
        };        
        recFun(data);       
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" ng-model="activeName" placeHolder="Enter name to search">
  <ul ng-repeat="parent in filteredNames = (Names | getSelectedNames: activeName)">
    <li>
      {{parent.name}}
      <ul>
        <li style="margin-left: 20px;" ng-repeat="child in parent"> {{child.name}}</li>
      </ul>
    </li>      
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: did you got an error by any chance? what did you tried?

Comment: No i did not get any error, its not giving me any result.